# Django button with javascript alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm improving my `Django` website and I would like to add `javascript button` with window alert when users clicked on this button.

I made that in my HTML template but I'm not sure How I have to write this. My script looks like :

```
<button onclick="myFunction()"> 
        <form class = "col-sm-10" method='POST' action="{% url "PDF" birthcertificate.id %}"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input class = "button" type ="submit" value="Générer le PDF des acte de naissance" />
    </button>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        alert("Votre PDF a été généré");
    }
    </script>


    </form>
```

But I get this kind of display :

[image]

I got 2 buttons, but I want to display only the bootstrap style.
Do you have any idea ?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because your HTML is invalid. The `<form>` element must wrap all the inputs within it, it should never be within a button. The reason for the two buttons is because you have used a `<button>` and `<input type="button">`. Again, they should not be nested. Try this fixed version:

```html
<form class="col-sm-10" method='POST' action="{% url "PDF" birthcertificate.id %}">
  {% csrf_token %}>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Générer le PDF des acte de naissance </button>
</form>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    alert("Votre PDF a été généré");
  }
</script>
```

Also note that using `on*` event attributes is considered bad practice as it couples the HTML and JS code directly, which is bad for Separation of Concerns. To fix this you can use an unobtrusive event handler. As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's how you can do that:

```js
$(function() {
   $('button').click(function() {
     alert("Votre PDF a été généré");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="col-sm-10" method='POST' action="{% url "PDF" birthcertificate.id %}">
  {% csrf_token %}>
  <button>Générer le PDF des acte de naissance </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! It's the first time I'm using javascript and jQuery so I'm sorry for my bad practice. I will try your answer with your solutions :)